# Green rep rectangle sticks out a little

Tags: bug, top-bar, achievements-dialog

[image]

When I hover it. I think its grey background should be resized too.

Comment: Solution: click it more often, don't wait until you have +99999 in there. :)

Comment: You don't have that much rep?

Comment: I disagree you don't know exactly what is happening server side. Whilst it's unlikely it may render differently than altering at runtime.

Comment: @AshleyMedway but I do! http://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtzV.png :-D

Comment: @AshleyMedway I rendered it exactly as Stack Exchange would render it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep! http://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UfY.png

Comment: @nicael I see you really try hard to break things!

Comment: @Anna if bug, it's surely by design so the next step is asking to change... the OP just skipped this extra step. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was going to ))

Comment: Nice humble brag.

Comment: @Won't You mean that *you* have now exactly 31k rep? ))

Comment: OOH!  FAKER!  Shame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

all.css, line 10758:

```
width: 36px;
```

Make it:

```
min-width: 36px;
```

`.topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count` could use some `margin-left` and `margin-right` too.

Comment: Now get hired by SE and fix this horrible bug! :-)

Comment: Do they hire kittens?

Comment: @user0000000 Doesn't Shog9 work remotely? (Not sure; SE does have an office in Denver, but that doesn't mean he's there).