# Overlay the achievement icon with reputation changes in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Yay! We have an achievements dialog: [Add a reputation and achievements pane to iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220429)

As previously part of that request, but now split off to its own, (as requested by Arie on the linked post) is overlays on the achievements icon:

[image]

Similar to the desktop version, and as done for the app inbox.

Comment: And what if there's +10000? ;)

Comment: Same as the desktop. Everything breaks.

Comment: I would love to see animation, like there was for tag badges. :D

Comment: +1 just because you cropped and resized.

Comment: @Sha +10000? [You have some new rep changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233645/green-rep-rectangle-sticks-out-a-little). I would check it but, eh, I don't have an iPhone...

Comment: @nicael yeah that's the post I was referring to when I said everything breaks :)

Comment: @Sha A, I see. Whose blame?

Comment: @nicael it wasn't me who replied, I was going to say that you inspire me. :D

Comment: @Sha yep, I am positively too old.

Comment: @nicael yeah, 100 y/o is not so young!

Comment: @Sha When you will be 100 years old, you will think that actually it isn't funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature has been implemented, as is available in beta builds since version 1.2.0.168.

The achievements button will update and render when there are any changes to achievements while the app is running (realtime changes); in addition, when the app is opened or foregrounded, it will also check and see if any changes have happened while the user was out (we only do this once every hour to save on cell/wifi data). This behavior should match up pretty closely to the desktop behavior.

**When some reputation is earned:**

[image: Achievements button with reputation]

**When some non-reputation-earning achievement (e.g. badges) occurs:**
[image]

**Also, the look is a bit different on iPad:**

[image]

Comment: Can it also become negative?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, in that case it will just show the highlighted (green button) state. We do the same on the site.

Comment: Also, the version now is 1.2.0.171 so does it mean you're rolling back to a previous version? (or did you mean 1.2.0.172? :))

Comment: Actually no, in the site if the delta is negative the icon is silent and not highlighted at all. (It's highlighted without a number only in case of new achievement)

Comment: @ShadowWizard regarding version, no roll-back – this feature has been around since then, but I only announced it now since some backend functionality was still pending. Regarding the negative status, thanks – I'll double check that behavior.

Comment: I can't tell if I'm supposed to be happy since this is an awesome feature or sad since now I need to rush to get it done on Android too.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nevermind, I was mistaken – the negative behavior was implemented correctly. (won't show anything if delta is negative). My memory was just a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Cheers, guess your memory remembered the desired behavior rather than the existing behavior. ;)

Comment: Nice! It works with badges and reputation! Thanks