# New reputation changes icon on top keeps association bonus in the calculations

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog, association-bonus

I joined [Moderators.se] this morning.

Ever since, whatever SE site I visit, the +100 association bonus I received stays being calculated 'into' the *new reputation changes* icon.

I have visited multiple SE sites in multiple browser sessions, and downvoted questions/answers during those sessions, and saw the icon value dropping from +100 to currently +94.

The icon does not become gray when I revisit and do only no-reputation-changing things.

Comment: No repro. Just to be sure, you **click on the icon**, right? (only clicking it would reset it)

Comment: Goodness me - I probably did not click it all that time (because if was obvious what that change was from). Deleting my question in a few minutes...

Comment: I suggest not to delete your question. It adds something valuable to the total experience and know-how pool.

Comment: @JanDoggen: well, I did assume that you clicked on the icon, so we were both caught out by assumptions here. :-P

Comment: @Sha Maybe you'll answer it then?

Comment: @nicael sure, thought there's a dupe but alas, couldn't find. :/

Comment: @Sha http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233645/green-rep-rectangle-sticks-out-a-little#comment766983_233645

Comment: @nicael what about it? It's not a dupe by any means.

Comment: @Sha Comment I linked to. We should mark this question as dupe of *that* comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter we get on the achievements dialog is not being reset on its own, you need to click it in order to reset it, then it will start counting again. (Remember: only positive change would show)

So this "bug", is a classic [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).